# How to display data from TableView on a DetailsView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a HomeTableViewController which consists of two sections. When you click on ANY cell, it directs the user to the DetailsViewController. The DetailsViewController has 2 labels. One in the cell number, the other is the due date. To direct my cell to my details view controller I have the following code: **This is in my HistoryTableViewController.m**

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // HistoryDetailsViewController *HDV = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HistoryDetails"];
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:HDV animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"index path section--%i",[indexPath section]);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Push" sender:indexPath];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {
        HistoryDetailsViewController *detailVC=(HistoryDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

Now that I'm able to access my DetailsViewController, I want to control its labels. I want to be able to modify the labels **ACCORDING TO THE SECTION OF THE CELL I TAPPED ON.**

However when I try something like

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Push"]) {
        HistoryDetailsViewController *detailVC=(HistoryDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        detailVC.labelCellNum.text = @"Cell test";
        detailVC.labelDueDate.text = @"Date Test";
    }
}
```

I can't even modify the label's text using this code. I don't understand.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many posts about this -- you can't do it because the detailVC's view hasn't been loaded yet at the time you try to set the text, so detailVC.labelCellNum and detailVC.labelDueDate will be nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it would be to have a property for each string you'd like to use in the detail view: (declared in .h)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringOne;
```

Then in the prepareForSegue, I would assign a certain value to it:

```
[detailVC setStringOne:@"Some string"];
```

And in the viewDidLoad method of the Detail VC, I'd set that string somewhere I want to use it:

```
[self.labelCellNum setText:self.stringOne];
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Now I just need a way to get my Cell's text and display THAT in my details view controller. Except in my prepareforSegue I can't set the text to cell.textlabel.text

Comment: How would I be able to get the value of my cell.textlabel.text within my prepareForSegue method?

Comment: That's the reason I don't like prepare for segue methods, though you could also make another property in the main view controller (like Selected Text, Selected index), then in the prepareForSegue method, assign that value to the detail view controller.